# XmlStreamReader test method error: Cannot User getText on START_ELEMENT

Tags: xml

This is the same question posted on [developer.salesfoce](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000kAxeIAE).

I've completed a method on XmlStreamReader, it is now working fine, can extract the data out correct. But the issue is with the test class coverage.

[image]

Below is my code:

Post method:

```
//Variables store data
public static String toUserName {get; set;}
public static String fromUserName {get; set;}
public static String msgType {get; set;}

@HttpPost
    global static void doPost(){
        //Set up for XML processing
       RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        string strMsg = req.requestBody.toString();  
        System.debug('Request Contents' + strMsg);
        XmlStreamReader reader = new XmlStreamReader(strMsg);
        //Deserialize
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            if(reader.getLocalName() == 'ToUserName'){
                reader.next();
                if(String.isNotBlank(reader.getText())){
                    toUserName = reader.getText();
                }
            }
            else if(reader.getLocalName() == 'FromUserName'){
                reader.next(); //failed from here below
                if(String.isNotBlank(reader.getText())){
                    fromUserName = reader.getText();
                }
            }
            else if(reader.getLocalName() == 'MsgType'){
                reader.next();
                if(String.isNotBlank(reader.getText())){
                    msgType = reader.getText();
                }
            }
            reader.next();
        }
    }
```

Test Method:

```
static testMethod void testDoPost(){
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        String strTmp = '<xml><ToUserName>tUN</ToUserName><FromUserName>fUN</FromUserName><MsgType>mT</MsgType></xml>';
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueOf(strTmp);
        req.requestURI = 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Demo//CoreService';
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';
        test.startTest();
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;
        ApexRESTCycle.doPost();
        XmlStreamReader reader = new XmlStreamReader(req.requestBody.toString());
        test.stopTest();
        System.assert(ApexRESTCycle.fromUName == 'fUN');
        System.assert(ApexRESTCycle.toUName == 'tUN');
        System.assert(ApexRESTCycle.mType == 'mT');
}
```

The issue now is in the Post method, only the first node  got covered, other nodes are not covered, error attached on above.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working. In case this might help with others, just post the code and troubleshooting steps out.

I have replicated the Post in [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com), then found out the same issue in error message. Althought I am still not very sure why in real, all XML elements posted correctly？ Welcome if any explaination for this point.

Then I looked into my XML data structure and found out for every node, there is a start element with opening tag, like `<ToUserName>` or `<FromUserName>`. That was what was missing in original code, so I added them up.

This is my revised code:

```
 while(reader.hasNext()){
            if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT && reader.getLocalName() == 'ToUserName'){
                reader.next();
                toUName = reader.getText();
            }if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT && reader.getLocalName() =='FromUserName'){
                reader.next();
                fromUName = reader.getText();
            }if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT && reader.getLocalName() == 'MsgType'){
               reader.next();
                mType = reader.getText();
            }reader.next();
}
```

Of course, I will add an extra condition to eliminate if the Character is not null just like previous did.